# Login to PostgreSQL using md5 encrypted password and not plaintext password

Tags: postgresql, authentication, passwords, md5, psql

I have created an user using md5 encrypted password as follows:

```
create user testuser with encrypted password 'md54ca03099a7cd3945e0260801ff5972a3';
```

The encrypted password is combination of "md5" + md5(password+username)

```
password=test
username=testuser
```

Added entry for testuser in pg_hba.conf file with md5 method

Now I am trying to login using above created user as follows:

```
psql -d dbexpress -U testuser
```

It prompts for password. I have provided above encrypted password so it is giving me error as:

```
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "testuser"
```

But I am able to login to postgresql using plaintest password "test".

Comment: you have to pass `password` along with `psql -d dbexpress -U testuser` this is because you have `Added entry for testuser in pg_hba.conf file with md5 method` or change `md5 Method` to `Trust`

Comment: what is 'md54ca03099a7cd3945e0260801ff5972a3'? is it first you generate and than put into above query?

Comment: what you provide as password? is it 'md54ca03099a7cd3945e0260801ff5972a3'?

Answer (score 14):

The authentication method `md5` does not directly govern the encryption of passwords in the system catalog (the keyword `ENCRYPTED` in `CREATE ROLE`):

#### Postgres 10 or later

Note this [update in Postgres 10](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/release-10.html#id-1.11.6.21.5.3.8)

> - Add SCRAM-SHA-256 support for password negotiation and storage
>   (Michael Paquier, Heikki Linnakangas)
>
>   This provides better security than the existing md5 negotiation and
>   storage method.

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/auth-password.html)

> To ease transition from the md5 method to the newer SCRAM method, if
> md5 is specified as a method in `pg_hba.conf` but the user's password on
> the server is encrypted for SCRAM (see below), then SCRAM-based
> authentication will automatically be chosen instead.

#### Postgres 9.6 or older

[Per documentation on the **authentication method**:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/auth-methods.html#AUTH-PASSWORD)

> The password-based authentication methods are md5 and password. These
> methods operate similarly except for **the way that the password is sent
> across the connection**, namely MD5-hashed and clear-text respectively.

[Per documentation on the **`ENCRYPTED` keyword** in `CREATE ROLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-createrole.html):

> `ENCRYPTED`
> `UNENCRYPTED`
>
> These key words control **whether the password is stored encrypted in the system catalogs**. (If neither is specified, the default behavior
> is determined by the configuration parameter password_encryption.) If
> the presented password string is already in MD5-encrypted format, then
> it is stored encrypted as-is, regardless of whether `ENCRYPTED` or
> `UNENCRYPTED` is specified (since the system cannot decrypt the
> specified encrypted password string). This allows reloading of
> encrypted passwords during dump/restore.

Both use md5 encryption, but the first is concerned with *transport* and the second with *storage*. You are still expected to provide the ***unencrypted* password** for your login, even when using the authentication method `md5` (setting in `pg_hba.conf`). The user name is used as *salt* for md5 encryption on client and server.

#### First matching entry in `pg_hba.conf`

About your remark:

> Added entry for testuser in pg_hba.conf file with md5 method.

Don't just "add" an entry. The *first* matching line in `pg_hba.conf` is applied!

The manual on `pg_hba.conf`:

> The **first record** with a matching connection type, client address,
> requested database, and user name is used to perform authentication.

Bold emphasis mine in all quotes.

Comment: Yes I have added entry and ensured that it is considering this entry itself in pg_hba.conf file. 

My requirement is that I am passing encrypted password through jdbc so Postgres should recognize this password as an encrypted and allow user to login or is there any mechanism so that we can decrypt the password at postgres side before login?